# WooCommerce: Adding category description to single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I've tried adding `<?php do_action('woocommerce_archive_description'); ?>` to `content-single-product.php` template file, but it's not showing up.

Is there any way to add the WooCommerce category description to single product page?

Answer (score 3):

To add category description to single product page, using `content-single-product.php` template file, this code did the trick:

```
<?php 

    global $post;
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
    $count = count($terms); 
    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo $term->description;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Could you add the source link reference for this code and could you give some usage explanations (where and how), please. It could be helpful for community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display the product category description to single product page -

```
<?php global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();
$term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );
echo $term->description; ?>
```